# How to turn on row numbers and turn off field names will using QueryTable for Text Import

Tags: vba, excel

I need to import a text file using a QueryTable object and return row numbers along with the data. However, setting `RowNumbers` property to `True` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Setting `FieldNames` also does not appear to matter (field name *always* show), but I can live with that for purposes of my use case.

Example using publicly available data:

```
Sub ReadTestData()

    Set QT = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    With QT
        .Name = "TestData"
        .FieldNames = False 'doesn't seem to matter
        .RowNumbers = True 'doesn't seem to matter
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm working in Excel 2010. Why don't these flags seem to do anything?

Comment: tried on excel2016 ... no row numbers, even after numerous refreshes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-rownumbers-property-excel), `.RowNumbers` will not work until you refresh:

"Setting this property to True doesn't immediately cause row numbers to appear. The row numbers appear the next time the query table is refreshed, and they're reconfigured every time the query table is refreshed"

Also, on [this site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-data-ranges-and-their-properties-c7d57506-64f6-40c9-a162-55e946f16f43) there is the following note concerning the row numbers checkbox (which turns the .RowNumbers property on and off when adjusting the External Data Range Properties)

```
NOTE: This check box is not available for an imported text file, XML file, or Web query.
```

Comment: Notice the `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` in my code sample.

Comment: Agreed.  See the additional note in my answer.

Comment: Yuck. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry the answer is not what you wanted.  Nevertheless, if you explain and mark the post as answered it will help others in the future

Comment: One more thought:  it might be possible for you to add page numbers after each query is refreshed, using VBA.   It could just be a matter of putting in numbers adjacent according to the number of entries.  It all depends on how much you know about your data.